# Awarding a bounty to a deleted answer

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, bounties

I have offered a bounty to one of my previous questions  which hadn't not received enough attention. But I got a nice answer after I offered the bounty.

I decided to wait for a few more answers, so I didn't award the bounty to that specific answer at that time. I didn't get a better answer afterwards, and the previous answer I felt good was deleted by the user who answered it.

Is it possible to give the bounty to the deleted answer or at least directly to the user who answered instead of giving it to some answers that I don't like?

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16255732/1190388) question?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes..

Comment: The answer you are referring to was deleted by a moderator for being nothing more than a link to another SO question. If anything your question is a duplicate of the one linked to.

Comment: @ChrisF It might be just a link. But that only helped me..

Comment: @Udhay Might that mean that your question is a duplicate to begin with?

Comment: In that case I'll refund the bounty and close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Bart Yup! It is repeated. But i realized after getting that stackoverflow link in the answer i received only..

Comment: @ChrisF Hi, You can refund the bounty are you can award that to the user brothercake whose answer was linked for this question... Thanks :)

Comment: Yet another reason we should reward effort for finding dupes.  Here's a bounty -> work on question because of incentive -> solve by finding answer on SO -> whoops, no bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ChrisF♦ commented; the answer you are referring to is no more than a link to another question ([Find all CSS rules that apply to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element)) and provides a link further as given in one of [the replies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023174/1190388) in the aforementioned thread.

If you still consider it a good reply, then imho; your question should be closed as an exact duplicate instead.

Comment: Hey! It is showing something like "Cannot close the question sin it has some bounty" when i'm trying to close the question..

Comment: Use flag > other > close as duplicate