# The Pop-Up occurs, why is giving bounty to a deleted answer not prevented (is it really not)?

Tags: bug, bounties

When I try to give a bounty to a deleted answer, a pop-up occurs:

[image]

Nope, I didn't try - I didn't dare to. But why is it not prevented (or rather, is it really not prevented)?

I read up [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179173/awarding-a-bounty-to-a-deleted-answer) but the answer seems to focus more on why the answer got deleted rather than whether it is possible to give bounty to a deleted answer.